# working with regular expression

Tags: linux, shell

**I have some questions:**

1- In a file tu.txt how can i find all words that contain only upper-case letters, e.g. GFDY

2- How can i find multi-word terms in which only the first letter is capitalized, e.g. Royal kingdom castle

I prefer using grep.

Comment: Are you trying to match the lines that contain those words (the typical use of grep) or only those words themselves? What do you consider the terminator for a "multi-word term" -- only the end of the line or other symbols/punctuation?

Comment: Are you using linux grep tool?

Answer (score 1):

1)
`grep -w "[[:upper:]]\{1,\}" tu.txt`

where `[:upper:]` menas `[A-Z]` and `{1,}` means word having at-least one symbol from [A-Z].

2) What do you mean by "terms"?? Please clarify your logic..

Comment: i mean phrases in which only the first letter of the first word is capitalized